# Why caret symbol is not behaving greedy when used with asterisk in regexp

Tags: python, regex, regex-greedy

We all know `*` means 0 or more and unless used with non-greedy operator like `?`, it will always be greedy as much as possible.

```
>>> re.search('.*hello','hai hello there, hello again').group()
'hai hello there, hello'
>>> re.search('.*?hello','hai hello there, hello again').group()
'hai hello'
```

I just came across the following code and little surprised to see the behavior.

```
>>> re.search('\^*','abc^').group()
''
>>> re.search('a*','abc^').group()
'a'
```

With the pattern `\^*`, I expected it to match the one caret symbol which present in the string.

But, why it has to behave non-greedy by quitting with 0 occurrence of caret symbol, with empty string match ?

Is it because `^` is special to regular expressions ? If So, then how we can match that `^` with `*` symbol?

**Note :** Of course, with `\^+` as pattern, it will obviously match the literal caret symbol.

Comment: Strings are parsed from left to right, thus, your `\^*` matches the empty string at the start and `re.search` returns this first occurrence only.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : Gr8!!!. With `re.search('a*','bca^').group()`, it also returns the empty string. Engine parses`b` character first and quits there itself with zero matches. Thanks :)

Comment: So, asterisk will behave non-greedy if the searched pattern is not starting with the first character ?

Comment: `*` is always greedy. And then see my top comment.

Comment: Poor me. Sorry. Got it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex engine parses the input strings from left to right, thus, your `\^*` matches the empty string at the start and `re.search` returns the first occurrence only.

When you search for something, you should avoid using patterns that may match empty strings, and `\^*` is a pattern that matches 0 or more `^` symbols. Thus, the best solution is to use `+` instead of `*`.

Answer (score 0):

@Wiktor Stribiżew explained that re.search only return the first match. 
So:

1. re.search('\^*','abc^').group() returns the empty string; i.e. it matches 0 times the caret symbol at the start of the string and returned.
2. re.search('a*','abc^').group() matches 1 `a` at the begining of the string and retrun this `a`
3. re.search('b*','abc^').group() matches empty string for the same reason that the caret (case 1)

To answer your question "how we can match that ^ with * symbol?"
You can use a group `(\^+)*` and get the result of the group:

```
re.search('(\^+)*','abc^^ab').group()
```